# 'com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive' is deprecated

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using parts of the Saved Games sample app in order to save unlocked levels or purchased power-ups. If the user has saved these in Google Drive, he can restore these after reinstall the app or using another device with his google account.

After updating to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:18.0.0' i have got "deprecated" for

```
.requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
```

I read in https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation that

> The Drive Android API is deprecated as of December 6, 2018 and will be turned down on December 6, 2019.

My questions are:

1. Will be disabled the "deprecated" 
   .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) ?
2. If it will be disabled, why Saved Games Support in Android Games in https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames 
   promts to use 
   .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
   in the sample app CollectAllTheStars2 https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/CollectAllTheStars2/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/catt2/MainActivity.java ?
3. If it will be disabled, how can someone retain the Saved Games functionality?

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: I've also tried to find an answer for this. I have not seen any instructions what the developers should use instead. Good thing is that saving games in the deprecated way still works in 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:20.0.0'

Comment: You can find a solution for the Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER deprecation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321726/2419739

Answer (score 0):

In order to retain the Saved Games functionality i have replaced it with the Firebase Firestore data bases. In the [Firebase Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) can someone learn how to read and write his data.

Comment: You pay for it?