# Google Play games, 'Saved games' deprecated?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

Is Google Play games services, 'Saved Games' feature deprecated?

On their website Saved Games is not listed as deprecated. 
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames

However when specifying the Drive scope in code, Android studio gives code hints saying the feature is deprecated and on the Google Drive API website, it states this feature is deprecated.
https://developers.google.com/drive/android

The website advices to migrate to the Drive REST API?
and that website advices to migrate to Firebase Cloud Firestore.

> Clients requiring app data storage are strongly encouraged to migrate to a non-Drive solution such as Cloud Firestore.

Any clarity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The Drive API was deprecated. I guess saved games internal implementation uses the Drive REST API now.

Replace `Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER` with `new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER)` to clear the Lint warning. If you'll check the internals you'll see they are the same.